# PHP Specific optimization for if loop in Symfony

Tags: php, loops, symfony, if-statement, switch-statement

In Symfony app, i need to use switch/case function, but request parameters prevents me, and i use an uggly if condition like :

```php
        $roles = ["ROLE_USER"];

        if ($request->get('isAdmin')) {
            array_push($roles, "ROLE_ADMIN");
        }

        if ($request->get('isFreemium')) {
            array_push($roles, "ROLE_FREEMIUM");
        }

        if ($request->get('isPremium')) {
            array_push($roles, "ROLE_PREMIUM");
        }

        if ($request->get('isExternal')) {
            array_push($roles, "ROLE_EXTERNAL");
        }

        if ($request->get('isVip')) {
            array_push($roles, "ROLE_VIP");
        }
```

Can you help me to simplify it ?

Comment: You can make an associative array and make use of foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
$definedRoles = new ArrayObject([
    'Admin',
    'Freemium',
    'Premium',
    'External',
    'Vip',
]);

$roles = new ArrayObject([ 'ROLE_USER' ]);

foreach ($definedRoles as $role) {
    if ($request->get('is' . $role)) {
        $roles->append(strtoupper('role_' . $role));
    }
}
```

Why I 'm using the `ArrayObject` class? Because it works like a yield already. Unlike an array, the object occupies memory only for the current entry when iterated. Thus your loop occupies little memory and you do not load all entries into the memory.

Put all your valid roles into the first array `$definedRoles`. All the roles will be iterated and an if condition will check, if it 's in the `$request` object. If so, the role will be appended to the `$roles` array.

Comment: Just be aware that $request->get is deprecated in 5.4 and should no longer be used.  https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-controller-changes#deprecated-the-request-get-method